# Excel multiple running totals

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to make a simple formula for multiple running totals.

[image: Sample:]

Basically, it's for recording transactions for different accounts, showing the running total of that particular account for each row. So, it's impossible to use SCAN+LAMBDA function.  One way to do it is to have a set of helper arrays somewhere, but here I'm using another way, by using XLOOKUP.

`=C2+XLOOKUP(D2,D$1:OFFSET(D2,-1,),E$1:OFFSET(E2,-1,),0,,-1)`

Basically, it looks up the last account balance above the current row of the corresponding account and add the current transaction amounnt to it.  It works by draggin down to all the transaction rows.

Since the number of transactions is over 10 thousand, I was trying to minimize the file size by using named function with LAMBDA.

Name: AddtoBalance

`=LAMBDA(c,c+XLOOKUP(OFFSET(c,,1),Sheet1!E$1:OFFSET(c,-1,1),Sheet1!F$1:OFFSET(c,-1,2),0,,-1))`

And changed cell E2 to
`=AddtoBalance(C2)`

and dragged it down to all transaction rows.

However, after saving and re-opening, the cells are having errors.  I have to go to Name Manager, click Edit but without doing anything and Close it.  Then the cells becomes fine again.  It seems to me that when re-opening a workbook, the formulas are not calculated sequentially from top to bottom.  Is that right?  Is there any options to change it?

[image: Error:]

Comment: Your original formula can be simplyfied to: `=C2+XLOOKUP(D2,D$1:D1,E$1:E1,0,,-1)` that way it does not use the volatile `OFFSET` causing slow file, because of recalculation at a change anywhere in the file. That also prevents the circular reference.

Comment: Actually, I tried that before.  The reason I don't use it is because very often I need to copy a row and insert-paste it somewhere.  So using your formula will not work (because it directly reference another row).  I had to use only current row in the formula and use offset to get relative position of the previous row.  I tried using INDEX but suprisingly, it's slower than OFFSET.  Despite OFFSET being volatilie, I actually found no performance impact with OFFSET even though I have 10 thousand rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to hate me when you see this…

Put this in E2:

`=SUMIF( B$2:B2, B2, C$2:C2 )`

Then copy it down.  Mind the dollar signs, they are important.  You *could* place this in a named Lambda but the character count reduction is probably immaterial.

Comment: of course this works and was my original formula.  but when i have 10 thousands of rows, this is dreadfully slow whenever a row is inserted

Comment: @dohanin Hmmm.  To your other question, Excel does not calculate top-down.  Part of the “wisdom” of Excel is that is calculates a very robust dependency tree to determine the order of execution.  Also, OFFSET() is a volatile function, which means that by definition Excel’s dependency logic *does not* know how to interpret an OFFSET(), and thus it recalculates every OFFSET() formula every time.  I am fairly certain that the OFFSET is where you are running into trouble.  Also, have you just tried a `ctrl` `=` keyboard shortcut to force execution without having to go into name manager?

Comment: Thanks Max for your suggestion.  Well the reason I use OFFSET() is because I found it is faster than other functions like INDEX.  Anyway, I tried your suggestion, but weird things happened.  I tried both INDIRECT and INDEX and amended the LAMBDA function. I both works, but there was a warning of "circular reference" on the bottom.  Then after close and re-open, the same thing happens.  I had to go to Name Manager, edit and doing nothing, the values would be calculated again.

Comment: Probably it's nothing to do with OFFSET(), but it's because of the fact that the formula I use must be sequential from the top.  I tried to create dynamic array, e.g. use BYROW, it won't even work at the first time due to Circular reference.  However, if that's really the reason, I don't understand why if I don't use LAMBDA function, it would work.

Comment: Anyway, I have given up this approach.  Now I used a combination of SCAN, LAMBDA, ARRAYTOTEXT and TEXTSPLIT to have multiple running totals with spilled array.  Now the file size is small and computation is still fast when inserting rows. :)

Comment: So post that as an answer. It might be useful for others or somebody may come up with an alternate solution

Comment: @dohanin What I was working on last night and hadn’t quite tested was this approach:  XMATCH() allows you to look “up” by scanning in the reverse direction.  So the XMATCH in row 10 would start in B9 and search up to B2 for a match, the first match being the most recent instance.  So if the XMATCH() returns a number, that’s the index of the most recent C value, so E = C + indexed(C).  If not, this is the first instance so E = C.

Comment: yeah, XMATCH works too and similar to XLOOKUP in terms of performance

Answer (score 1):

After rebooting and restarting excel, actually I could not reproduce the error.  It works fine with the Lambda function now.

Answer (score 0):

Whole different approach, but how about:

```
=LET(f,ISNUMBER(C:C),
     c,FILTER(C:C,f),
     d,FILTER(D:D,f),
     s,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(d)),
MMULT(
      (d=TRANSPOSE(d))*(s>=TRANSPOSE(s)),
      c))
```

It first creates an array of `TRUE`'s and `FALSE`'s on column C:C if it contains a number. This is used to filter the values to be used from column C and D.
A sequence of the count of filtered values in column C is used to simulate it's row number in that filtered range.
Now `MMULT` checks row by row how many values of column D equal it's current value  where the sequence number for that "row" is smaller or equal than the current.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  That was my original intent to have a single formula that can spill the whole table.  However, I got "Excel ran out of resources while attempting to calculate on or more formulas.  As a result, these formulas cannot be evaluated", if I appy it for the whole table.  When I halfed the table, it works but extremely slow, I am afraid.

Comment: I was afraid so. Testing on my mobile got up to 3000 rows, but was slowing things down